# Create Nested Array

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

How can i create this array comes from my form, I have tried like below but it created `array: 0 and 1` but array 2 does not created, i know it because am using this  `if (count($request->pid) > 0) { foreach ($request->pid as $key => $v) {`

request->all()

```
array:12 [▼
        "_token" => "aXAkdBEVfO8nLMtxjUoHgxbvBkxMbJz4zIonOvFm"
        "projectdate" => "2021-08-30"
        "clientName" => "Emmanuel"
        "garamakaz" => "600"
        "amountpaid" => "7888"
        "Note" => "madirsha 50"
        "pid" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "1"
          1 => "1"
        ]
        "qty" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "10"
          1 => "10"
        ]
        "discount" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "500"
          1 => "500"
        ]
        "subtotal" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "479500"
          1 => "479500"
        ]
        "descExps" => array:3 [▼
          0 => "Ex1"
          1 => "Ex2"
          2 => "Ex3"
        ]
        "amountExps" => array:3 [▼
          0 => "45666"
          1 => "45666"
          2 => "45666"
        ]
      ]
```

Controller
this is my controller i used to created those data.

```
                public function store(Request $request)
                 {           
              if (count($request->pid) > 0) {
                    foreach ($request->pid as $key => $v) {
                        $data2 = ([
                            'projectno' => $fk,
                  'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
                            'pid' => $request->pid[$key],
                            'project_date' => $date,
                            'discount' => $request->discount[$key],
                            'qty' => $request->qty[$key],
                  'clientName'=>$request->clientName,
                  'costproject'=>$request->garamakaz,
                  'comment'=>$request->Note,
                            'amountpaid'=>$request->amountpaid,
                  'amount' =>$request->subtotal[$key],
                  'description_expenses' =>$request->descExps[$key],
                            'amount_expenses' =>$request->amountExps[$key]
                        ]);

                            $creatdata=Project::create($data2); 

                }
          }
```

what can i do to create all data comes from my form?, someone can help me on this

Comment: please write expected result and show print of $request->all()

Comment: @SirMissAlot, i edited by Qns, but what am expect is to store all `request->all()`